# System.class.getResource doesn't work in Play

Tags: java, playframework, classloader

I have a play project.
I try to execute:

```
System.class.getResource(/a/b/c/d)
```

And it returns with null. It's because the class loader is null.
If I execute:

```
play.Application.class.getResource(/a/b/c/d)
```

It works.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

EDIT:
I'll be more clear - I write a project in play, with a dependency to another project A. Somewhere inside project A there is a line code System.class.getResource(/.....) where the path is in project A.  When I write in my project a code that uses project A it fails in the getResource() with NullPointerException. Then I wrote a simple function in my project with two line. One is the System.class and the other is play.Application.class. the first line returns null, the second one returns the path.

Comment: Where is your resource located? What argument you used for `getResource` method?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments.

What type of application is this (e.g. desktop, server app, etc.).  Server apps tend to use more than one class loader so this can have effects on where resources are and are not accessible. In any case, the System classes might be loaded by a separate class loader in other applications as well.

Is the resource in the class path of the application?

What are you using to indicate the location of the resource.  It can be a relative or absolute path to the resource and the resource should be in the class path of the application.  If you are using an absolute path I think you might need to include an initial / in the locator string (e.g. /com/mycompany/myproj/mypkg/MyResource.txt instead of com/mycompany/myproj/mypkg/MyResource.txt).

You can also use something like play.getClass().getResource("/com/mycompany/myproj/mypkg/MyResource.txt")

Comment: Look at the 'EDIT'. I can't change the code the uses getResource. It uses an absolute path